# Unable to Login Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm unable to access the admin panel after deploying my Django project on an Ubuntu server using nginx and gunicorn, but wrong password is authenticated on admin panel still on entering correct details it reloads and shows admin panel login page again

## HTTPS SETTINGS

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

## HSTS SETTINGS

```
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3153600
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```